# Change functions in python instead of redefining them?

Tags: python, function, python-3.6

title says it - if I have a function like this one and want to change (the print output, for example) what do I besides redefining it???:

```
import sys
def UselessFunction(Weight, WeightIncrease):
    for Year in range(0, 16):
        Weight = Weight + WeightIncrease
        Weight_On_Moon = Weight * 0.165
        print('Your weight on the moon would be %s in the year %s' % (Weight_On_Moon, Year))
        Weight = Weight + 1
```

Want to change "Your weight on the...." to "On the moon you would be way lighter than on Earth! In fact, you would only weigh %s kg in the year %s' % (Weight_On_Moon, Year))

Thanks to all

Comment: You could pass a callback as argument. Otherwise you could return both values and print the output in different functions

Comment: You can ... (HERE BE DRAGONS!) ... override `print()` and do the replacement after the fact. But don't do it, that's a very bad idea and a thousand kittens will die if you do.

Comment: Im new to python - how do you pass a callback as an argument or print an output in different functions?? thanks

Comment: @zwer - how do i override `print` ? or put an output in different functions?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hokey example:

```
class ResultHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, output_str):
        self.output_str = output_str
    def handler(self, results):
        print self.output_str % (result[0], result[1])

def handle_output(func, args, callback):
    # compute moon weight and year
    results = func(*args)

    # Invoke the callback with the result
    # Specifc to this problem
    try:
        for result in results:
            callback(result)
    except TypeError:
        pass

# Try it here
r1 = ResultHandler('Your weight on the moon would be %s in the year %s')
r2 = ResultHandler('On the moon you would be way lighter than on Earth! In fact, you would only weigh %s kg in the year %s')
handle_output(UselessFunction, (12, 3), callback=r1.handler)
handle_output(UselessFunction, (12, 3), callback=r2.handler)
```